# How to get any asp:LinkButton to look like a button

Tags: asp.net, .net, css

I want a hyperlink that looks like a standard button. I have tried using a LinkButton but can't get it to look like a button. It always seems to stay looking like a hyperlink. I don't want to set an image to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use an Asp:Button?

Comment: An asp button will not always work in what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it through css.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton" CSSClass="btn" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

also define the following class in your css.

```
.btn{ text-decoration:none; border:1px solid #000; }
```

Answer (score 9):

Use css for this... like

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkButtion" CssClass="buttonClass" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Here you can specify your own colors

```
.buttonClass
{
    padding: 2px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid 1px Green;
    background-color: #ababab;
}
.buttonClass:hover
{
    border: solid 1px Black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<asp:Button OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<a href="mypage.aspx?param1=1" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <asp:Button PostBackUrl="mypage.aspx?param1=1" Text="my button-like link" runat="server" />
</a>
```

`style="text-decoration:none;"` is used to remove underling:
[Removing underline with href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528316/removing-underline-with-href-attribute)