# Removing underline with href attribute

Tags: html, href, underline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the underline for anchors(links)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks)

In the following code below, the link gets underlined when I use the href attribute.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="xxx.html">goto this link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the link to be associated with that  tag, but not to be underlined. How can I do that? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you searched in google before posting this question.....if you did any research before posting u will get correct result in first link....

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Add a style with the attribute `text-decoration:none;`:

There are a number of different ways of doing this.

**Inline style:**

```
<a href="xxx.html" style="text-decoration:none;">goto this link</a>
```

**Inline stylesheet:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   a {
      text-decoration:none;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="xxx.html">goto this link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**External stylesheet**:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="xxx.html">goto this link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

*stylesheet.css:*

```
a {
      text-decoration:none;
   }
```

Comment: or <a href="xxx.html" style="text-decoration:none;">goto this link</a>, or better yet put your css in another file.